# Rename Element Name in Generic Classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson and I am using generic class for response like this:

```
public class GenericListInfoResponse<T> extends GenericResponse {

    private T resultInfo;

    public GenericListInfoResponse(T resultInfo) {
        super();
        this.resultInfo = resultInfo;
    }

    public T getResultInfo() {
        return resultInfo;
    }

    public void setResultInfo(T resultInfo) {
        this.resultInfo = resultInfo;
    }

}
```

I setted some data comes from my service:

```
TitleListInfo titleListInfo = dropdownDataService.getTitleList(transactionId);
response.setResultInfo(titleListInfo);
```

After that it is return this kind of JSON:

```
{
  "resultInfo": {
    "combinedMessage": "",
    "messageCode": null
    ...
}
```

I want to rename element name instead of "resultInfo". For example "titleInfo"

Answer (score -1):

I gather that you want to do that without just changing name of the variable? Try annotating a field with `@JsonProperty("titleInfo")`, it should work.

```java
@JsonProperty("titleInfo")
private T resultInfo;
```

If it doesn't work, try annotating getter and setter instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need dynamic @JsonProperty name. I will reuse my this class another packege. And I wanna rename it for example userInfo, another place maybe meberInfo ...

Comment: Oh, sorry, seems kinda obvious that's what you wanted now that I read this. Have a look at that then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321155/jackson-generics-with-variable-jsonproperty-usage-with-generics

Comment: @Whatsz thank you it is correct. I flag my question as dublicated.