# Abstract Data Types and Json Mapping

Tags: java, annotations, pojo, abstract-data-type

I have a class that I use as a POJO for responses from a RESTful web service. I'd like to handle all responses with one class, they all come in the same format Status, ErrorCode, ResultCount, Some List of Objects. I'd like to write one class to handle the responses instead of 3. Is there a way when using Json annotations in Jackson to do this? For instance, i have this class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "Status", "ErrorCode", "ResultCount", "Clients" })
public class GetClientsResponse
{

    @JsonProperty("Status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("ErrorCode")
    private Integer errorCode;
    @JsonProperty("ResultCount")
    private Integer resultCount;
    @JsonProperty("Clients")
    private List<SpiviClient> clients = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

.......
}
```

I'd like to replace

```
private List<SpiviClient> clients = null;
```

with

```
private List<T> objects = null;
```

i dont know how to use these annotations for this purpose. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you're asking about Jackson; this will be completely dependent on the specifics of your serializer. You may be able to do something like using the `_class` JSON property, but you quickly get into very close coupling with your JSON representation.

Comment: Sorry, yes asking about Jackson. I'm not using a custom serializer, so i guess the default. How would the _class JSON property work in this case? what do you mean by close coupling with the JSON representation?

Comment: i guess i could look into polymorphic deserialization with jackson. I'm guessing thats what you were getting at. The different objects aren't really related apart from being objects right now. I could make them all extend some common class. ill look into it, thank you.

Comment: "Coupling" meaning basically that your browser JavaScript (for example) and all other clients have to know to put `_class: "FooClient"` inside each JSON subobject, and the specific class tag becomes part of the public API.

Comment: [Jackson generics with variable JsonProperty usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321155/jackson-generics-with-variable-jsonproperty-usage-with-generics)

Answer (score 0):

[Jackson generics with Variable JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321155/jackson-generics-with-variable-jsonproperty-usage-with-generics)