# Jackson Generics with variable Json response object and Json property

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Based on the answer '[Jackson Generics with variable JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389626/961143)' by VizGhar, I am trying to use WebClient to consume an API response which contains a generic object in json response:

```
{
"meta": { 
    "RID": "abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n",
    "QID": "abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n" },
"data": { 
        "Inquiry": {
            "multiCurrency": [{"TaxStat": "Y", "TaxAmt": 0}],
            "Type": "Tax",
            "TaxFreq": { 
                "weekDay": 0,
                "startDay": 0 
            },
            "TaxRegion": "Tx" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Where type of "Inquiry" would be generic, i.e. "data" is a wrapper around a generic response object which is 'Inquiry' in this case, but it may change.

Inquiry.java:

```
public class Inquiry {
    @JsonProperty("multiCurrency")
    private List<MultiCurrencyInq> multiCurrency;

    @JsonProperty("Type")
    private String Type;

    @JsonProperty("TaxFreq")
    private TaxFreq taxFreq;

    @JsonProperty("TaxRegion")
    private String TaxRegion;

    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

MultiCurrencyInq.java:

```
public class MultiCurrencyInq {

    @JsonProperty("TaxStat")
    private String TaxStat;

    @JsonProperty("TaxAmt")
    private int TaxAmt;

    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

TaxFreq.java:

```
public class TaxFreq {

    @JsonProperty("weekDay")
    private int weekDay;

    @JsonProperty("startDay")
    private int startDay;

    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

My Response.java looks like this:

```
public class Response<T>{
    private Meta meta;
    private Data<T> data;
    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

Meta.java:

```
public class Meta{
    private String RID;
    private String QID;
    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

Data.java:

```
public class Data<T> {
    // property name, that will be changed
    @JsonProperty(DataNamingStrategy.DATA_FIELD)
    private T data;
    // Getters Setters Constructors
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class InquiryController {

    @Autowired private WebClient webClient;

    @GetMapping("/inquiry") public Response<Inquiry> getInquiryApiResponse() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://my.org.com/clientId/inquiry")
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(String.class)
                .block();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new DataNamingStrategy("Inquiry")); 
        JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory()
                .constructParametricType(Response.class, Inquiry.class);

        Response<Inquiry> res = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), type);
        return res;
    }
}
```

DataNamingStrategy.java:

```
public class DataNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy{

    // used by other classes (this will be default field name that should be changed)
    public static final String DATA_FIELD = "variable:data";
    private String fieldName;

    public DataNamingStrategy(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    // use this to change field name (format "variable":"value") not needed in my case
    @Override
    public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedField field,
            String defaultName) {
        return (defaultName.equals(DATA_FIELD))?
            fieldName :
            super.nameForField(config, field, defaultName);
    }

    // use this to change setter method field name (JSON -> Object with format "variable":{})
    @Override
    public String nameForSetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config,
            AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {
        return (defaultName.equals(DATA_FIELD))?
            fieldName :
            super.nameForGetterMethod(config, method, defaultName);
    }

    // use this to change getter method field name (Object -> JSON with format "variable":{})
    // should be same as nameForSetterMethod
    @Override
    public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config,
            AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {
        return nameForSetterMethod(config, method, defaultName);
    }
}
```

This is not working for me. What could be the reason for not setting the generic type to **"Inquiry"** for **@JsonProperty(DataNamingStrategy.DATA_FIELD)** in Data.java

Comment: My two cents: Jackson library has changed lately. That might also cause this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What could be the reason for not setting the generic type to "Inquiry"
> for @JsonProperty(DataNamingStrategy.DATA_FIELD) in Data.java

The reason is that by default `JsonProperty` annotated property name cannot be renamed by `DataNamingStrategy`. Jackson has [this](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING) feature which is disabled by default.

> ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING Feature that when enabled will allow
> explicitly named properties (i.e., fields or methods annotated with
> JsonProperty("explicitName")) to be re-named by a
> PropertyNamingStrategy, if one is configured. Feature is disabled by
> default.
>
> Since:
> 2.7

All you need to do is to enable this feature -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING);
```

---

Here is the related Jackson notes history (referred from [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/release-notes/VERSION-2.x))

```
Prior versions allowed explicit property renaming by default
v2.4 - Jackson stopped allowing property renaming. (#428)
v2.7 - Introduced ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING feature to allow / disallow Explicit Property renaming (#918)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the deserialization directly with the WebClient and with the ParameterizedTypeReference class. Below is your working example:

Response from the code below (Inquiry and DummyEntity):

```
// Inquiry Entity
ThirdPartyAPIResponse(meta=ThirdPartyAPIResponse.Meta(rid=abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n, qid=abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n), data=ThirdPartyAPIResponse.Data(data=Inquiry(multiCurrency=[MultiCurrencyInq(taxStat=Y, taxAmt=1)], type=Tax, taxFreq=TaxFreq(weekDay=1, startDay=1), taxRegion=Tx)))

// Dummy Entity
ThirdPartyAPIResponse(meta=ThirdPartyAPIResponse.Meta(rid=abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n, qid=abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n), data=ThirdPartyAPIResponse.Data(data=DummyEntity(code=200, message=Hello World)))
```

**Inquiry**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171.entities;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Inquiry {
    
    @JsonProperty("multiCurrency") private List<MultiCurrencyInq> multiCurrency;
    @JsonProperty("Type") private String type;
    @JsonProperty("TaxFreq") private TaxFreq taxFreq;
    @JsonProperty("TaxRegion") private String taxRegion;
    
}
```

**MultiCurrencyInq**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class MultiCurrencyInq {

    @JsonProperty("TaxStat") private String taxStat;
    @JsonProperty("TaxAmt") private Integer taxAmt;
    
}
```

**TaxFreq**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class TaxFreq {

    @JsonProperty("weekDay") private Integer weekDay;
    @JsonProperty("startDay") private Integer startDay;
    
}
```

**Dummy Entity**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class DummyEntity {

    @JsonProperty("code") private Integer code;
    @JsonProperty("message") private String message;
    
}
```

**ThirdPartyAPIClient (WebClient Impl)**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171.third_party;

import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import com.stackoverflow.q69665171.entities.Inquiry;

@Component
public class ThirdPartyAPIClient {

    private WebClient webClient;

    public ThirdPartyAPIClient() {
        webClient = WebClient.create();
    }
    
    // The port is for testing scopes only, as the mock web server
    // defines a random one
    public ThirdPartyAPIResponse<Inquiry> getInquiryApiResponse(int port) {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("http://localhost:" + port + "/test")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<ThirdPartyAPIResponse<Inquiry>>(){}
            ).block();
    }

    public ThirdPartyAPIResponse<DummyEntity> getDummyEntityApiResponse(int port) {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("http://localhost:" + port + "/test2")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<ThirdPartyAPIResponse<DummyEntity>>(){}
            ).block();
    }

}
```

**ThirdPartyAPIResponse**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171.third_party;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class ThirdPartyAPIResponse <T> {

    @JsonProperty("meta") private Meta meta;
    @JsonProperty("data") private Data <T> data;
    
    @Getter @Setter @ToString
    public static class Meta {
        @JsonProperty("RID") private String rid;
        @JsonProperty("QID") private String qid;
    }
    
    @Getter @Setter @ToString
    public static class Data <T> {
        @JsonAlias({"Inquiry","DummyEntity"}) private T data;
    }
    
}
```

**Json Dummy Entity**

```
{
    "meta":{
       "RID":"abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n",
       "QID":"abc9f-defgh-hj78k-lkm9n"
    },
    "data":{
       "DummyEntity":{
          "code": 200,
          "message": "Hello World"
       }
    }
 }
```

**Test**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q69665171;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import com.stackoverflow.q69665171.third_party.ThirdPartyAPIClient;

import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;

@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {

    private static MockWebServer webServer;
    @Autowired private ThirdPartyAPIClient client;
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws IOException {
        webServer = new MockWebServer();
        webServer.start();
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() throws IOException {
        webServer.shutdown();
    }

    
    @Test
    void should_Retrieve_Inquiry_Response_When_Consumes_Inquiry_API() throws Exception {
        
        final String thirdPartyResponse = readJsonTestResource("response.json");
        //System.out.println(thirdPartyResponse);
        
        // Mock
        webServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .setBody(thirdPartyResponse)
        );
        
        System.out.println(client.getInquiryApiResponse(webServer.getPort()));
        
        assertEquals(0, 0);
        
    }

    private String readJsonTestResource(String fileName) throws Exception {
        File resource = new ClassPathResource(fileName).getFile();
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));
    }

    

    @Test
    void should_Retrieve_Dummy_Entity_Response_When_Consumes_Dummy_API() throws Exception {
        
        final String thirdPartyResponse = readJsonTestResource("response2.json");
        //System.out.println(thirdPartyResponse);
        
        // Mock
        webServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .setBody(thirdPartyResponse)
        );
        
        System.out.println(client.getDummyEntityApiResponse(webServer.getPort()));
        
        assertEquals(0, 0);
        
    }

}
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.q69665171</groupId>
    <artifactId>69665171</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>69665171</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The same example above works with Jackson but instead of ParameterizedTypeReference, the TypeReference class is used but for optimization, it's better to perform deserialization with the same WebClient.

Comment: I dont' have control over Response Objects. For e.g. 'Inquiry' object can not be modified with any Jackson annotations. Third party API response objects are produced using their YAML schema.

Comment: Could you explain better? In the example you can extend to any specification of the defined generic. So if the API returns another entity than Inquery you can specify it in the response with the ParameterizedTypeReference.

Comment: Now if it's for example to call an EndPoint that responds to different entities that you don't know (which violates the REST specification) what you can do is follow the same dynamics of the example but before parsing the response you should by means of a regular expression define the target entity to be deserialized.

Comment: But in the normal case, you will know in advance the possible entities that the API will respond to, so with the example above you can handle the different types of possible entities that it returns in generic way.

Comment: In the ThirdPartyAPIResponse class with the JsonAlias annotation, you can define all the different names that your entity can take e.g "Inquiry", "Other Entity Name".

Comment: Excuse me, I updated the answer by adding a new entity (Dummy Entity) that follows the structure of the defined generic but has its own different fields to Inquiry Entity.

Comment: Can I do it without hardcoding @JsonAlias in
    public static class Data <T> {
        @JsonAlias({"Inquiry","DummyEntity"}) private T data;

I will be having hundreds of DummyEntity, and hard-coding them may not be possible.

Comment: In that case, you could change the JsonAlias to JsonUnwrapped so that it ignores the parent name of the generic property. But I haven't tried it.

Comment: Really appreciate your time and help. However, @SKumar's response has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Don't worry, it seems to me that the selected answer is the one indicated to your question :)