# mask for json property in java object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to create some kind of mask for `json` property in Java using `Jackson`?

My `json` has a lot of similar fields

```
"records":[
    {
        "ShippingStreet":null,
        "ShippingState":null,
        "ShippingPostalCode":null,
        "ShippingCountry":null,
        "ShippingCity":null,
        "BillingStreet":null,
        "BillingState":null,
        "BillingPostalCode":null,
        "BillingCountry":null,
        "BillingCity":null,
```

I have to create two objects - one for `Shipping` fields and one for `Billing` fields. Here is the example of `BillingAddress`

```
public class BillingAddress {

    @JsonProperty("BillingStreet")
    private String billingStreet;

    @JsonProperty("BillingState")
    private String billingState;

    @JsonProperty("BillingPostalCode")
    private String billingPostalCode;

    @JsonProperty("BillingCountry")
    private String billingCountry;

    @JsonProperty("BillingCity")
    private String billingCity;
```

And I have to create the almost the same object for `Shipping` fields.
As the result my java object for `json` has two fields with different type but almost the same functionality

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Account {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private BillingAddress billingAddress;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;
```

Is it possible to create some kind of mask where I do not need of two types of objects but use one type but define the type of fields they work with. For example something like this. 
One object

```
public class Address {

    @JsonProperty("*Street")
    private String street;

    @JsonProperty("*State")
    private String state;

    @JsonProperty("*PostalCode")
    private String postalCode;

    @JsonProperty("*Country")
    private String country;

    @JsonProperty("*City")
    private String city;
```

And two fields with the same type

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Account {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    @Annotation("Billing*")
    private Address billingAddress;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    @Annotation("Shipping*")
    private Address shippingAddress;
```

Comment: Good question. All I can think of is using some heavy introspection, or manipulating the json text before deserialising - neither of which jackson will do for you.

Comment: Well the problem is that I use some library that uses jackson to deserialize object - so basically it returns me already created `Account` object. So everything I am able to do is to operate with existing jackson fuctions. Or I should parse it manually - it can return `Map` too.

Answer (score 1):

Very challenging question. I have tried this, and my output is

`"records":[
{"Accountcity":"CHE","Accountstate":"TN"}
{"Billingcity":"TRI","Billingstate":"TN"}]`

May be you can refer it. Please let me know if any.

Service Side:

```
@GET
@Path("bil")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response sendBill(@HeaderParam("Accept") String accept) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    Records records = new Records();
    Account account = new Account();
    Billing billing = new Billing();
    Address address1 = new Address("CHE","TN");
    Address address3 = new Address("TRI","TN");
    account.setAccountAddress(address1);
    billing.setBillingAddress(address3);
    records.setAccount(account);
    records.setBilling(billing);

    return Response.ok(convertToJSON(records), accept).build();
}

private String convertToJSON(Records records) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    convert(mapper,"Account");
    String account = mapper.writeValueAsString(records.getAccount());
    System.out.println(account);
    ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
    convert(mapper1,"Billing");
    String billing = mapper1.writeValueAsString(records.getBilling());
    System.out.println(billing);
    System.out.println("\"records\":["+account+ billing + "]");
    return "\"records\":["+account+ billing + "]";
}

private void convert(ObjectMapper mapper,String prefix){
    Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("city",prefix+"city");
    map.put("state",prefix+"state");
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new ReplaceNamingStrategy(map));
}
```

Comment: `ReplaceNamingStrategy` from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915630/jackson-modify-an-attribute-at-runtime-without-annotation