# Jackson: Serializing object with list of tags

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to serialize Java POJO into Json with capitalized property names. I'm using `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)` for that and for the most part its working correctly except for `Tags` list. The the property names are still coming as lower case. What do I need to make them capitalized?

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Snapshot implements Serializable {
    private String snapshotIdentifier;
    private String clusterIdentifier;
    private Date snapshotCreateTime;
    private String snapshotType;
    private String status;
    private List<Tag> tags;

   ...
   ...
```

ex:

```
{
        SnapshotIdentifier: 'rs:dnd-1',
        ClusterIdentifier: 'dnd-1',
        SnapshotCreateTime: '2020-03-03T17:58:46.173Z',
        SnapshotType: 'automated',
        Status: 'available',
        Tags: [{ key: "test", value: "my-tag" }] <--- need to convert `key` and `value` to capitalized just like other properties
      },
```

Comment: You can set naming convention globally on `ObjectMapper` instance using `setPropertyNamingStrategy` method. [Modify an attribute at runtime without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915630/jackson-modify-an-attribute-at-runtime-without-annotation) or annotate `Tag` class with `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)` as well.

Comment: I used setPropertyNamingStrategy. Thank you